# Exporting a function with RequireJS in Node returns an empty object

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, mocha.js

How do you export a function from a RequireJS module in Node? With the code I have, I get an empty object rather than the Backbone model I'm expecting.

`first.js` contains:

```
'use strict';
var define=require('amd-define');
define(function (require) {

var Backbone = require('backbone');

// Our basic **Todo** model has `title`, `order`, and `completed` attributes.
var Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({
    // Customizations of my model...
});

return Todo;
})
```

My test file `test.js` contains:

```
'use strict';
var chai =require("chai");
var assert=chai.assert;
var expect=chai.expect;
var Todo=require("first");

describe('Tests for Todo model', function () {
    it('should create global variables for Todo', function () {
        expect(Todo).to.be.exist;
        console.log(typeof (Todo))
    });

    it('should be created with default values for its attributes',               function() {
        var todo = new Todo();
        expect(todo.get('title')).to.equal('');
    });

    it('should fire a custom event when state change', function() {
        var todo = new Todo();
        todo.set({completed: true, order: 1});
        todo.set('title', 'my title');
    });
});
```

It gives the error that `Todo` is not a function. The `console.log` statement prints `object`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package `amd-define` is either buggy or does not support the [CommonJS sugar](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#sugar). (The latter is probably the case. I do not see any code in it that takes care of doing the dependency transformation necessary for supporting the CommonJS sugar.)

I recommend dumping `amd-define` and using [`amd-loader`](https://github.com/ajaxorg/node-amd-loader) instead. I've used it for years, it works.

For your code:

1. Remove `var define=require('amd-define');` from `first.js`.
2. Add `require('amd-loader')` (after installing it) in your test file *before* you load any AMD module.

I was able to get an export from `first.js` doing this.

Comment: But the problem with that is that it doesnot load thirdparty libraries like q and my.Class which are installed through bower used by the code and not npm used in mocha to install amd-loader.